# Converting bytes to integer in Python

Tags: python, arduino

I need some help in retaining an integer datatype through serial communication. My setup right now is an Arduino microcontroller reading a temperature sensor which is outputting a float number through an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) module via the serial port that looks like this: 76.82 for example.

The XBee receiver is hooked up to my computer in which a Python program reads using the `readline()` method from the serial module. However, when I do `readline()`, I receive `b'76.66\r\n'`. How do I remove all the characters and just keep the numbers in its original datatype?

**Here is my Python code:**

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(6)

while True:
    x = ser.readline();
    print(x)
```

**Here is my code for the Arduino:**

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 3

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

DeviceAddress Thermometer = { 0x28, 0x36, 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF0 };

void setup(void)
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    sensors.begin();
    sensors.setResolution(Thermometer, 12);
}

void printTemperature(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
    float tempC = sensors.getTempC(deviceAddress);
    Serial.println(DallasTemperature::toFahrenheit(tempC));
}

void loop(void)
{
    delay(5000);
    sensors.requestTemperatures();

    printTemperature(Thermometer);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
>>> a = b'76.66\r\n'
>>> float(a)
76.66
```

**EDIT:** If by *"retain the original datatype"* you mean "keeping it as a string":

```
>>> a.strip()
'76.66'
```

Comment: @TabishChasmawala - Happy this solved the issue. As you are new, I hope you don't mind if I remind you that when an answer solves your issue, you should select it as accepted. Beside giving reputation points to the answerer (which is ultimately the only reason we all answer to questions!) it is also important for future visitor to immediately see that the issue has been solved for good. Only one answer per question can be marked as accepted. If more than one answer is correct, you normally choose the one that was posted first, or the most complete/clearer one. Welcome on StackOverflow! :)

Comment: Okay I accepted the answer as you said but I can't vote the answer up as I do not have enough reputation. But when I do I will definitely start participating widely in the StackOverflow community. Thanks for the welcome as well as for the help!

Answer (score 3):

To convert to a float:

```
float(b'76.66\r\n')
```

To round that down to an int:

```
math.floor(float(b'76.66\r\n'))
```

Comment: `int(float(b'76.66'))` would accomplish the rounding-down portion without having to import another module.